# How to add comman data in a list of

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts which has a lot of values like

```
"resultset":[
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"10",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"11",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"10",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"14",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Lambo ",
       "Value_in_US":"11",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Porshe Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"12",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Porshe Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"10",
    },
 ]
```

I am trying to separate the list of unique Cars with corresponding values, The output i am expecting is

```
{
'Porshe Nine' : [10,12],
'Lambo': [11],
'Aston Martin DB Nine': [10,11,10,14]
}
```

I was trying something like

```
test = {}
    for data in  result['resultset']:
        test[data['Car']] = ???
```

I am not sure how to get the values right as i mentioned

Comment: You should have custom class instances instead of dictionaries on the inner level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be useful here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
test = defaultdict(list)
for data in result['resultset']:
    test[data['Car']].append(data['Value_in_US'])
```

Very similar logic to the code you already have, but what `defaultdict` lets you do is assume that there's already a key/value pair of car:list of prices. Notice that we don't need to check if the car is already in the dictionary, we just append the price.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional imports:

```
test = {}
for data in result['resultset']:
    if not data['Car'] in test.keys():
        test[data['Car']] = []
    
    test[data['Car']].append(data['Value_in_US'])
```

works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to do this easily

```
resultset = [
 {'Car': 'Aston Martin DB Nine', 'Value_in_US': '10'},
 {'Car': 'Aston Martin DB Nine', 'Value_in_US': '11'},
 {'Car': 'Aston Martin DB Nine', 'Value_in_US': '10'},
 {'Car': 'Aston Martin DB Nine', 'Value_in_US': '14'},
 {'Car': 'Lambo ', 'Value_in_US': '11'},
 {'Car': 'Porshe Nine', 'Value_in_US': '12'},
 {'Car': 'Porshe Nine', 'Value_in_US': '10'}]

from itertools import groupby
f = lambda d: d['Car']
res = {k:[d2['Value_in_US'] for d2 in g] for k,g in groupby(sorted(resultset, key=f), f)}
print(res)
```

**Outout**

```
{'Aston Martin DB Nine': ['10', '11', '10', '14'],
 'Lambo ': ['11'],
 'Porshe Nine': ['12', '10']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dict/list comprehension should do the trick if you like inline expressions,

```
resultset=[
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"10",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"11",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"10",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Aston Martin DB Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"14",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Lambo ",
       "Value_in_US":"11",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Porshe Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"12",
    },
    {
       "Car":"Porshe Nine",
       "Value_in_US":"10",
    },
]

#init with empty list for each cars
result = {dic['Car']:[] for dic in resultset} 

#append the value to each car entry
[result[dic['Car']].append(dic['Value_in_US']) for dic in resultset]
print(result)

>>>> {'Aston Martin DB Nine': ['10', '11', '10', '14'], 'Lambo ': ['11'], 'Porshe Nine': ['12', '10']}
```

Here is a [good guide](https://medium.com/@joshuapaulrobin/dictionary-comprehension-in-python3-for-beginners-54fb4ddd3982) on medium to start with dictionary comprehension.